# error while registering a .txt file on admin in django

Tags: html, django

I am trying to register a log file(.txt) file but there is an issue.
the model is below-

```
class LogRegister(models.Model):
class Meta:
    managed = False
```

and code for registering on admin is-

```
from logs.models import LogRegister
from .helper import get_latest_logs

@admin.register(LogRegister)
class JsonDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def logs_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    text = get_latest_logs(BASE_DIR + '/logs/concat_logs/concat.txt')
    html = "<br>".join(text.split('\n')) #adding <br> tag between lines
    context = dict(
        self.admin_site.each_context(request),
        html=html,
    )
    return TemplateResponse(request, "logs.html", context)
```

now it is working fine but text on admin panel is coming on same line evern if 
 tag is there. so how do i make it come on new line if 
 tag is encountered.

the html for logs.html is -

```
{% block content %}
<h1> Errors are-</h1>
<p>{{ html }}</p>
```

{% endblock content %}

Comment: Try ... return TemplateResponse(request, "<app_name>/logs.html", context)

Comment: @EneP hey, now it is working but there is an issue. I have updated the post.